# Wildcard argument in a method mock, to match anything?

Tags: rhino-mocks

When I'm making an `Expect.Call(mock.method(arg1, arg2 ..))..`, is there a way by which I can make one of the method arguments a wildcard so the mock will match it no matter what the runtime argument value is?  Otherwise, is there another means to achieve this behaviour using Rhino Mocks?

*Rhino Mocks 3.6*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heh. Shortly after posting I found the [`IgnoreArguments()`](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks/api/files/Interfaces/IMethodOptions-cs.html#Rhino.Mocks.Interfaces.IMethodOptions.IgnoreArguments) method:

```
        Expect.Call(dataAccessMock.SetCustomer(oCustomer, out strOutCustId))
            .IgnoreArguments();
```

which states:

> // Summary:
>   //     Ignores the
>   arguments for this method. Any
>   argument will be matched againt [sic]
>   // this method.